# JW source 6 compilation issue with Flash CS5 and Flex SDK

Tags: flash, jwplayer

Please help me getting JW source 6.5 compile ( with flash CS5 and Flex SDK ). I am not newbie.. things were fine with JW source 5 but not good with JW 6 (may be its skin issue).

For link http://atlers.com/jwtest/2/ I tried to set skin and for link http://atlers.com/jwtest/1/ used default skin six.xml.

I have set Flex SDK path correctly and resolved following issues:
First I found that semicolon warning in if condition in imageLoaded

> srccomlongtailvideojwplayerviewcomponentsTooltipThumbnails.as, Line 132    Warning: 1106: Empty statement found where block of code expected. Did you type ';' accidentally?

So I removed that `;` after if condition in  `imageLoaded` function (TooltipThumbnails.as file)

After that I get error (run time error that probably occurs because loadExternal function look for parametesr from html/js)

> LOG (STARTUP: Error occurred during player startup: Error loading player: Could not load player configuration)

So ignore that error because this `loadExternal()` function will probably take parameter from HTML/JS .

Now what to do ? I am using Flash CS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. We need to change `var _version` value to 6.4.3359 and it works.
The solution is strange but it is a solution.

```
protected static var _version:String = "6.4.3359";
```